# How to stretch image programmatically?

Tags: php, html, css

There is a vertical bar on my homepage. It is actually an image that looks something like this:

[image]

The white boxes are the place-holders for the product images that will be added dynamically. I want to know how to stretch the blue vertical bar as new product images are added. This must be done programmatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the image as background and repeat it vertically.

Something like this

```
<style>
    .pageBG { background: url(your_image_source) repeat-y; }
</style>
<div class='pageBG'>
    <!--your content goes here -->
</div>
```

From your image I think you can make a small image of dimension 5*5 or something and make it repeat vertically and horizontally. For that you don't have to set the background position, because `repeat` is the initail value for **[background-position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530721%28VS.85%29.aspx)**.

Comment: +1 Simply use a smallpart of the image, and set it as background of a div.

Comment: As long as the image really is the homogeneous texture the OP posted, I second this.

Answer (score 1):

Why to use image at all? Why not simply set the background color for the div:

```
<style>
    .pageBG { background: #35f; }
</style>
```

You do not need a white hole in the background to display an image.

Comment: I think the white hole is an indicator on the bar, not a place holder for an image.